# Ionic android release (signed) APK is not woking

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've designed a beautiful app Yes Jobs on latest ionic's android platform.

I have used HTTPS apis for secured connection.

I have generated debug.apk `ionic cordova build android --prod` ==> working fine through side loading app through USB

I have generated release.apk `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` ==> app is open but the first API of login itself doesn't work, ultimately application on working on release version

I have read some where about the generate keystore in every version of release.

***Please tell me the reason or solution why application in debug.apk is working but not the release version***

Comment: release version gets crash or throws error...?

Comment: build again app and check logs check which library is not updating

Comment: What i feel is...it is only my HTTPS request in api which is not getting called, will it be issue of SSL validation of my APIs

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't have to generate keystore in every version of release you have to just once.

Secondly you have to sign your app smoothly if you ready to publish your app. You should

use **jarsigner** with the JDK tool for this and get a signed apk for publish. If you

don't know how do thes step you should check this link :>

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html